# CURL does not show all OPENSSL engines on Linux

Tags: curl, openssl, amazon-linux-2, openssl-engine

When I run

```bash
bash-4.2# openssl engine
(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
(pkcs11) pkcs11 engine
```

But when I run

```bash
bash-4.2# OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf curl --engine list
Build-time engines:
  rdrand
  dynamic
```

- I am using Amazon Linux 2 to build curl and libcurl 8.2.1 using openssl 1.1.1g. But despite my efforts to get to list all the OpenSSL engines, I cannot get it to work.
- I have looked at `curl/lib/vtls/openssl.c` 1705 and tried to add more init flags like `OPENSSL_INIT_ENGINE_OPENSSL` but to no avail.
  Please assist me in this.

I am trying to get CURL to list all the OpenSSL engines.
And despite my efforts to make CURL souce code work to list all of the engines, I could not.

I was expecting to get all the engines but setting the config file correctly and building curl with openssl.

I am not sure but I do have a preinstalled version of curl that I cannot remove.

And to confirm that I am running the the correct version of curl, I did explicitly launch it and it reported the following:

```bash
bash-4.2# ./curl --version
curl 8.2.1-DEV (Linux) libcurl/8.0.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips zlib/1.2.7 libidn2/2.3.0 libssh2/1.4.3 nghttp2/1.41.0
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL threadsafe UnixSockets
WARNING: curl and libcurl versions do not match. Functionality may be affected.
```

I am not sure how to proceed.